# Insalling custom Sound-Schemes in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound

As a former Windows user, I have become attached to the ability to install custom sound-schemes (or custom sounds effects for various events).  Seeing as I have found no way to do this in the Ubuntu operating system itself, is there a good 3rd-pary application which allows me to do such a thing?  Thanks for the help!